# what is the correct place to put code that reoccurs on every page in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

In my mvc solution I was originally using a viewModel to hold an IEnumerable of SelectListItems. These would be used to populate a dropdownfor element like below

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Type, Model.PrimaryTypeList, new { data_acc_type = "account", data_old = Model.Type, @class = "js-primary-account-type" })
```

the problem being that whenever I had to return this view, the list would need re-populating with something pretty heavy like the following:

```
if(!ModelState.IsValid){
 using (var typeRepo = new AccountTypeRepository())
            {

                var primTypes = typeRepo.GetAccountTypes();
                var primtype = primTypes.SingleOrDefault(type => type.Text == model.Type);
                model.PrimaryTypeList =
                    primTypes
                    .Select(type => new SelectListItem()
                    {
                        Value = type.Text,
                        Text = type.Text
                    }).ToList();

                }
  return View(model);
}
```

It seemed silly to me to have to rewrite - or even re-call (if put into a method) the same code every postback. - the same applies for the ViewBag as i have about 6 controllers that call this same view due to inheritance and the layout of my page.

At the moment i'm opting to put the call actually in my razor. but this feels wrong and more like old-school asp. like below

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Edit Account " + Model.Name;

List<SelectListItem> primaryTypes = null;
using (var typeRepo = new AccountTypeRepository())
{
    primaryTypes =
        typeRepo.GetAccountTypes()
        .Select(t => new SelectListItem()
        {
            Value = t.Text,
            Text = t.Text
        }).ToList();
}
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Type, primaryTypes, new { data_acc_type = "account", data_old = Model.Type, @class = "js-primary-account-type" })
```

Without using something completely bizarre. would there be a better way to go about this situation?

UPDATE: While semi-taking onboard the answer from @Dawood Awan below. my code is somewhat better, still in the view though and i'm 100% still open to other peoples ideas or answers.

#### Current code (Razor and Controller)

```
  public static List<SelectListItem> GetPrimaryListItems(List<AccountType> types)
    {
        return types.Select(t => new SelectListItem() { Text = t.Text, Value = t.Text }).ToList();
    }
    public static List<SelectListItem> GetSecondaryListItems(AccountType type)
    {
        return type == null?new List<SelectListItem>(): type.AccountSubTypes.Select(t => new SelectListItem() { Text = t.Text, Value = t.Text }).ToList();
    } 

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Add New Account";
    List<SelectListItem> secondaryTypes = null;
    List<SelectListItem> primaryTypes = null;
    using (var typeRepo = new AccountTypeRepository())
    {
        var primTypes = typeRepo.GetAccountTypes();
        primaryTypes = AccountController.GetPrimaryListItems(primTypes);
        secondaryTypes = AccountController.GetSecondaryListItems(primTypes.SingleOrDefault(t => t.Text == Model.Type));
    }
            
}
```

Comment: Because HTTP is stateless protocol you need to call your method every time you want view. But you could put that in session or cache so you don't need to pull it from DB every time. But, in my op you must put that code in method - some utility helper, and re-call it on every callback.

Comment: Yeah, While I fully understand the statelessness of http/mvc. It just seems like there should be a better way to handle something like this. even if I could put the options in a hidden field and then use a viewmodel or something. On top of that, thats not necessarily the problem. It just seems silly that accross several postback methods, in several controllers I have to repopulate, just to avoid doing it within my view. when the same thing will happen with less code.

Comment: I would say your first solution is correct. The controller is the correct place to build the selectlist from the models and the viewmodel is the correct place to hold the selectlist. To reduce lines of code, you could make a second SelectList returning repository. To reduce DB/CPU hit you could cache the result.

Comment: HOWEVER! if your second dropdown is populated based on the selected item in the first dropdown ? consider sending the full list of secondary options, writing them out as json and populating the select box dynamically client side with jquery (or lib of choice)

Comment: Put common code such as generating and assigning select lists into a private method (say) `private void ConfigureViewModel(MyModel model) { model.PrimaryTypeList = new SelectList(....) }` which you call in the GET method, and in the POST method if model state is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

In practice, you need to analyse where you app is running slow and speed up those parts first.

For starters, take any code like that out of the view and put it back in the controller. The overhead of using a ViewModel is negligible (speed-wise). Better to have all decision/data-fetching code in the controller and not pollute the view (Views should only know how to render a particular "shape" of data, not where it comes from).

Your "Something pretty heavy" comment is pretty arbitary. If that query was, for instance, running across the 1Gb connections on an Azure hosted website, you would not notice or care that much. Database caching would kick in too to give it a boost.

Having said that, this really is just a caching issue and deciding *where* to cache it. If the data is common to all users, a static property (e.g. in the controller, or stored globally) will provide fast in-memory reuse of that static list.

If the data changes frequently, you will need to provide for refreshing that in-memory cache.

If you used IOC/injection you can specific a single static instance shared across all requests.

Don't use per-session data to store static information. That will slow down the system and run you out of memory with loads of users (i.e. it will not scale well).

Comment: again, my main problem isnt having to call the database. its the fact that whatever I have to do has to be recalled over several possible postbacks. so if validation fails on any of those postbacks, then I need to re-populate the lists. so from a code perspective. the least amount of code possible would be writing it once in the view itself

Comment: Again: putting code into a view is a bad idea. If you look at the way pages are generated you will see you are actually saving nothing, but breaking separation of concerns. If you are worried about view-reuse, use a partial view.

Comment: Yeah, I know it is. Guess its just laziness on my part for being lazy and not wanting to write the same line of code for every potential postback. I've put it in my controllers now anyway.

Comment: If you are not using IOC (assumed) you can always have a common `BaseController` the other controllers derive from and put it there.

Answer (score 0):

If the DropDown Values don't change it is better to save in Session[""], then you can access in you View, controller etc.

Create a class in a Helpers Folder:

```
public class CommonDropDown
{

    public string key = "DropDown";


    public List<SelectListItem> myDropDownItems
    {
        get { return HttpContext.Current.Session[key] == null ? GetDropDown() : (List<SelectListItem>)HttpContext.Current.Session[key]; }
        set { HttpContext.Current.Session[key] = value; }
    }

    public List<SelectListItem> GetDropDown()
    {

        // Implement Dropdown Logic here
        // And set like this:
       this.myDropDownItems = DropdownValues;
    }
}
```

Create a Partial View in Shared Folder ("_dropDown.cshtml"):
With something like this:

```
@{
    // Add Reference to this Folder
    var items = Helpers.CommonDropDown.myDropDownItems;
}


@Html.DropDownList("ITems", items, "Select")
```

And then at the top of each page:

```
@Html.Partial("_dropDown.cshtml")
```

Comment: That was just a rough example. I use session for my main menu to avoid doing exactly that. However the actually list in question would be dynamic. Just to complicate things. Anyone reading this thread with something static would be best advised to use session, or just manually writing your list.

Comment: But the Dynamic List, is this bringing back values from the Same Location/Database Table?

Comment: its more like I have one static list for the primary types. and another one that is fetched dynamically from the selected primary type

Comment: So you could extend this GetDropDown() and pass parameters to filter list from the Session instead of the DB

Comment: I could do. nice idea! but in reality i'd still be hitting something every time. while not a db, the session is still pretty intensive. and still requires things to be re-populated.

definitely looks like the right general direction to be heading in though. thanks

Comment: Once you filtered you can save that filtered list in the session too, with a different key. Like that you won't perform search everytime

Comment: Saving that much data to user Session state is not a very scalable solution, so this approach is best avoided.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie agreed. that's why I'm 'on the right general direction'

Comment: Change Session to MemoryCache and you are good though https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache%28v=vs.110%29.aspx